# Picasso load images with horizontal lines

Tags: android, picasso, android-image, image-caching

I have used Picasso for loading images in my Gallery page with Recyclerview and load images from Server. It works great on all devices good,**except Samsung S4 device**.In S4 device the images are corrupted and it displays some **horizontal lines on all images**.What is the problem in my code.Also I think on same S4 device it works fine before updating my supports library versions from 22.2.1 to 23.3.0.

**GalleryAdapter.java**

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(GalleryViewHolder galleryViewHolder, final int position) {

            // Load images from Assets using Picasso library.
            Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);

            //picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
            //picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

            if(AppUtilities.isNetworkConnected(context)){
                picasso.load(imagesArrayList.get(position).getUrl())
                        .placeholder(android.R.color.darker_gray)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                        .into(galleryViewHolder.galleryImageView);
            }
            else{
                picasso.load(imagesArrayList.get(position).getUrl())
                        .placeholder(android.R.color.darker_gray)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(galleryViewHolder.galleryImageView);
            }
    }

    public class GalleryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected ImageView galleryImageView;

            public GalleryViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.galleryImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_imageview);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think there is a problem in your _if..else..._ condition. Just print a log in both condition. I think both may be executed.

Comment: @PiyushGupta This is issue occurs even there is no if else code. It occurs even if put else case code alone.

Comment: Try to use another placeholder

Comment: As your code looks fine, I recommend digging through the [issues](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues) from the library and finally open one by yourself if you found nothing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, before setting the image just set it to null like this:

```
galleryViewHolder.galleryImageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```